# Juju Controller and charms connection

Tags: networking, juju, maas, lxc, lxd

just a few questions as USER.

If I want to depoly an application with 2 different JuJu charms (let say DB + Mediawiki), on 2 different machines (or LXD), do I need 2 controllers ? If so, who manages the 2 controllers ?

Is there a some kind of controller "Master" ?

Lastly, when  i deploy an apllication through CLI, am I acting on the controller (telling to it to do deploying) ?

The controller "tells" to a charm to speak with another one (on a different machine) with a IP address through add-relation, but where (or how) are specified the IP addresses ?

Thanks a lot for the explanations.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. you do not need 2 controllers for your 2 charms:

   - You can deploy them in your model by `juju deploy mediawiki` and `juju deploy mysql`
   - then you can add a relation between them: juju add-relation `mediawiki:db mysql`
2. On each controller you have a superuser that is created when the controller is bootstrapped. by using `juju show-controller` you can see this:

   `account:
   user: admin
   access: superuser`

   - this user can create new models or add new users to a controller/model. This user can do anything on your controller.
3. The way charms communicate with each other is by the help of interfaces. Mysql will provide a DB and that Interface has a `provides.py` file where all the necessary information will be provided to the requires side (MediaWiki). The Requires side of the interface has a `requires.py` file that will get the information and pass it to the charm.

   - Every interface can provide or require different things. you can find them on http://interfaces.juju.solutions/
   - now the 2 charms are connected Mediawiki will know what the IP address is of MySql to make a connection with it.

If you still need extra information, you can find a lot of information on the [JUJU docs](https://jujucharms.com/docs/2.0/getting-started)

Comment: Many thanks for the explanations, just a comment. We can deploy (add) any juju machines that we want before in the model (environment) configuration and then deploy charms into them. So For 2 (or 3) Host Pc we need only on one controller for the management. Is this right ?

Comment: If those machines are all in the same cloud or same MAAS setup you only need 1 controller. If you have 2-3 computers I would suggest you install maas en configure them as 1 environment. Only one controller will be needed then en you will be able to use the resources of multiple computers in one model if you want. If you are going to use your computers separately and bootstrap a localhost LXD controller you will need to bootstrap one controller on each machine(computer) and they will each have their own models.

Comment: So if we have 2 charms  into 2 LXD containers (but we can think also to 2 phisical PCs) into 2 different pc (same local network) how can they comunicate ?. Are 2 controllers sharing a common model ? How charms speak in this scenario (my scenario) ?                                                                       Many thanks Sebastien

Comment: 2 charms into 2 LXD containers in the same model then they will simply communicate by using `juju add-relation mysql mediawiki:db`.  If they are each in an LXD container on a different machine( so not in the same model) you will have to expose your mysql (`juju expose mysql`) and have a look at how the mediawiki charms makes his connection with a database and then manually change your mediawiki config because at the moment it is not yet possible to share a model between 2 controllers